# disconnect failed firebase data real time

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a small problem with storing data in my Firebase Realtime Database.

I have a text view that contains some data like a time and an email. I want them to be stored as strings in the realtime database but it's not working.

This is my current code:

```
myref2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange (@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot){
        int flag = 0;
        for (DataSnapshot d : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            DonorHistory ado = d.getValue(DonorHistory.class);
            if (ado.dtime.equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(time))) {
                flag = 1;
                Toast.makeText(Donor_page.this, "Please wait unile donate again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        if (flag == 0) {
            DonorHistory ado = new DonorHistory(emaildonor, amountofmony, cardtype, time);
            String id = myref2.push().getKey();
            myref2.child(id).setValue(ado);
            Toast.makeText(Donor_page.this, "Donate successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the data's class:

```
public class DonorHistory {
    String demail,dmoney,dcard,dtime;

    public DonorHistory() {
    }

    public DonorHistory(TextView emaildonor, String amountofmony, String cardtype, TextView time) {
        this.demail = demail;
        this.dmoney = dmoney;
        this.dcard = dcard;
        this.dtime = dtime;
    }

    public String getDemail() {
        return demail;
    }

    public void setDemail(String demail) {
        this.demail = demail;
    }

    public String getDmoney() {
        return dmoney;
    }

    public void setDmoney(String dmoney) {
        this.dmoney = dmoney;
    }

    public String getDcard() {
        return dcard;
    }

    public void setDcard(String dcard) {
        this.dcard = dcard;
    }

    public String getDtime() {
        return dtime;
    }

    public void setDtime(String dtime) {
        this.dtime = dtime;
    }
}
```

This is the error in laycut:

```
2021-01-02 00:57:51.405 6348-6542/com.example.adopt_pet_app W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0xe3d74808 disconnect failed
2021-01-02 00:57:51.405 6348-6542/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0xc9dda9e0, 0xe3d74800
2021-01-02 00:57:51.405 6348-6348/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/ViewRootImpl@efbf5a4[Toast]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
2021-01-02 00:57:51.433 6348-6348/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=87
2021-01-02 00:59:51.987 6348-6348/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@f4daa94[Donor_page]
2021-01-02 00:59:51.987 6348-6348/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2021-01-02 00:59:51.987 6348-6348/com.example.adopt_pet_app V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=com.example.adopt_pet_app ic=com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@8a144d3 mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
2021-01-02 00:59:51.988 6348-6348/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2021-01-02 00:59:52.001 6348-6348/com.example.adopt_pet_app I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2021-01-02 00:59:52.010 6348-6348/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=74
2021-01-02 00:59:52.011 6348-6348/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=82
2021-01-02 00:59:52.519 6348-6348/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/ViewRootImpl@fa02221[Donor_page]: stopped(true) old=false
2021-01-02 00:59:57.094 6348-6542/com.example.adopt_pet_app W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0xdbeff808 disconnect failed
2021-01-02 00:59:57.094 6348-6542/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0xc9795280, 0xdbeff800
2021-01-02 00:59:57.133 6348-6348/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/ViewRootImpl@fa02221[Donor_page]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x5 surface={false 0} changed=false
2021-01-02 00:59:57.133 6348-6348/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/ViewRootImpl@fa02221[Donor_page]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
2021-01-02 00:59:57.133 6348-6348/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@f4daa94[Donor_page]
2021-01-02 00:59:57.134 6348-6348/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect? Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: It is very hard to help with something like "it's not working", as we have no way of knowing what specific doesn't work. When you step through the code in a debugger, which specific line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Did you found solutions